# Unresolved external symbol when using std::wstring

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker-errors

I declared the the following class:

```
#pragma once

#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

namespace util
{

class FileReader
{
public:
    FileReader();
    ~FileReader();

    bool open(const std::wstring& name);
    void close();
    bool read(std::vector<char>& buf, __int64 startFrom, int size);
    __int64 size() const;

private:
    FILE* m_file;
    std::wstring m_name;
    __int64 m_size;
};

}
```

And its implementation:

```
#include "FileReader.hpp"

namespace util
{

bool FileReader::open(const std::wstring& name)
{
    if (!name.empty() && (m_name != name))
    {
        close();
        if (_wfopen_s(&m_file, name.c_str(), L"rb") == 0)
        {
            m_name = name;
            // Get the file size
            _fseeki64(m_file, 0, SEEK_END);
            m_size = _ftelli64(m_file);
            rewind(m_file);
        }
        else
        {
            m_file = NULL;
        }
    }
    return (m_file != NULL);
}
// ....
}
```

in a seperate library and use it like this:

FileTransfer.cpp

```
#include <util/FileReader.hpp>

// .....    

if (!m_fileReader.open(m_localFileName))   //   std::wstring m_localFileName;
{
    ::MessageBoxA(NULL, "Failed to open file", "Error", MB_ICONERROR);
    stopFileTransmission();
    return;
}
```

in another project. Both projects compile successfully, but the FileTransfer.obj fails to link:

> Error 2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: bool
>   __thiscall util::FileReader::open(class std::basic_string,class
>   std::allocator > const &)"
>   (?open@FileReader@util@@QAE_NABV?$basic_string@GU?$char_traits@G@std@@V?$allocator@G@2@@std@@@Z)
>   referenced in function
>   __catch$?onRequestDirClicked@FileTransferWindow@@AAEXXZ$0 C:\Users\x\Documents\dev\Server\FileTransfer.obj    Server

I remember it was working when I used `std::string`, so I assume it has something todo with `std::wstring`.

Any idea what could be the issue?

Comment: It won't resolve your issue,but my first comment is that you should avoid adding `include` directives into your headers unless the headers themselves use the symbols. And even then, prefer forward declaration.

Comment: I assume the implementation is also in namespace `util`?

Comment: Yes, the implementation of `bool FileReader::open` is within the namespace `util`

Comment: Are you sure the file containing filereader got rebuild after you changed the prototype to wstring? If not, the function in the file would still be `filereader (string)` instead of `filereader (wstring)`, which would lead to this error.

Comment: Yes, I have definitely cleaned and rebuilt the fileReader.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, the problem was that the two projects had different values for the setting

> Treat wchar_t as built-in type

Setting it to **No (/Zc:wchar_t-)** for both projects, solved the linker error. I still don't really know what the consequences will be though.

Comment: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dh8che7s.aspx) recommends the opposite

Comment: For anyone else that may encounter this: Check if you have _DEBUG defined in you preprocessor. If you have it defined, the linker will attempt to link with debug CRTs.

Answer (score 0):

try using extern "C" to declare the open function.